# Django, how to assign a record to a different staff member?

Tags: django, django-models

```
class Enquiry(models.Model):   

    CONSULTANT = {             
        ('JAS', "do@do.com"),   
    } 

    first_name  = models.CharField(max_length=35) 
    last_name   = models.CharField(max_length=35) 
    email       = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    phone_num   = models.CharField(max_length=35) 
    message     = models.TextField(max_length=3000, blank=True, default='')
    processed   = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    assigned_to = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=CONSULTANT, default='JAS')
    date_added  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

These records are submitted from the website.
The problem is, i am trying to initially have all enquiries go to me. do@do.com, but on the admin dashboard i have created, I will have a href for enquiries.
The staff member will only get enquiries that have been assigned to them.

I don't know how to go about this.
should i make `assigned_to` field a `ForeignKey`,  if so O have a custom user that inputs email and password.
or should i use something like `request.user.id`. should i somehow find my id, and set this as default.
or is there a better method.

Maybe I should assign the user or email address as a dictionary in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is counter intuitive to get this done using a character field. `assigned_to` must be a `ForeignKey` to `User` model (using `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

You can then write a helper method that returns the default assignee (as a `User` instance). The email is hard coded in the following example for simplicity, but it is recommended to make it a user configurable value (through database or settings) in production:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

def get_default_assignee():
    User = get_user_model()
    try:
        return User.objects.get(email='do@dodo.com')
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return None


class Enquiry(models.Model):
   ...
   assigned_to =  = models.ForeignKey(
      settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
      default=get_default_assignee, blank=True, null=True)
   ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i can see how this works, but no way on planet earth could i have come up with this. I am greatly indebted.